# Defining variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I don't quite understand why the following is throwing an exception in Haskell's interpreter:

```
...
Prelude> let x = 3
Prelude> x
3
Prelude> let x = x + 1
Prelude> x 
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

x + 1 prints the result 4, however why can't I store it back in x. It does work when I store it in a variable y. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: In Haskell, *there are no variables*. Only constants.

Comment: AJFarmar above me is right, but you do have `STRef`s & `IORef`s.

Comment: For what `x` does `x = x + 1`? Are you thinking of infinity?

Comment: @MasterMastic In general, it better to make new constants instead of dipping into IO.

Comment: @PyRulez Indeed, but there are rare circumstances in which you really need mutability. So it is nice for the OP to be aware that such things exist, even if they are not going to be used routinely.

Comment: @duplode Oh definitely. It just that we don't want people thinking "Oh, I'm I have to add a new element to this set. I guess that means I need a mutable variable." (Sometimes that's true, but it is by no means the default.)

Comment: @PyRulez Certainly, but we also don't want the opposite extreme, that is, people thinking that Haskell forbids mutability because it is purely functional. I guess our comments nicely balance each other out :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your GHCi session, `x = x + 1` is not an assignment to the `x` you defined earlier, but a redefinition of `x`. The first definition, `x = 3`, is not used at all. What follows can be understood by replacing `x` with its new definition...

```
x
x + 1
(x + 1) + 1
((x + 1) + 1) + 1
-- ad infinitum
```

... which leads to infinite recursion.